# Graphics.py window works on windows but not on mac

Tags: python, graphics

I am working on a project in which I am using graphics.py to build a graph. I spent some time trying to work on it in Mac OS but no matter what I did the window would always appear brown with none of the elements (shapes and text) i was trying to add to it.

Here is my code:

`

```
from graphics import *
def main():
    win = GraphWin("Sankey", 1000, 1000)
    c = Circle(Point(3, 5), 20)
    c.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
main()
```

`

I tried running the same code in windows and for some reason it worked. Would anybody know why this is?

Comment: The problem is likely related to the fact that [`graphics.py`](https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/) was last updated 6 years ago, and there have been a lot of changes to MacOS since then. Do regular Tkinter apps work on your computer?

Comment: @MattDMo Ah that makes sense. I just tried to load the Tkinter demo thing (via python -m tkinter) and it's pretty clear that it's not working the way it's meant to so it seems there's not much I can do. Is there a more up to date graphics library that I could use? I'm pretty sure all I need is to be able to make polygons and add text.

Comment: How did you install Python (or are you using the system Python?) and what version of macOS are you on? If you're using the system Python, its version of `tkinter` is borked, so it's highly recommended you install Python from https://python.org, and install the bundled `tkinter` libraries as well. Make sure you add the new Python installation to your `$PATH` as the very first entry.

Comment: @MattDMo I did what you said and it seems to have fixed the issue, thank you so much!